# MadelineProto php как получить все диалоги с которыми я общался?

Tags: php, telegram, madelineproto

MadelineProto php как получить все диалоги с которыми я общался и прочитать их id и title?
messages.getAllChats я думал мне поможет , но я не понимаю как он работает.

https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/messages.getAllChats.html

except_ids - я не знаю ,что отправлять

```
$messages_Chats = $MadelineProto->messages->getAllChats(array("except_ids"=> [-10000000000, 10000000000]) );

$chats = $messages_Chats['chats'];

echo count($chats)+"\n";
foreach(array_reverse($chats) as $i => $chat){       
    echo $chat['id']."\n";   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dialogs =  $MadelineProto->getFullDialogs();
foreach ($dialogs as $dialog) {
    $MadelineProto->logger($dialog);
}
```